# Can not authenticate device to use with Windows Your Phone app

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account, your-phone

I used Windows your phone app quite often. But I changed my phone and couldn't add new device. So, I reset the app on Windows. So now, when I opened the app, it said:

> “We are having issues authenticating your devices.”

I logged out from my Microsoft account and tried with a different account. Still the same issue. The error appears on top of the page. I can still generate the QR code and scan it on phone, but both devices can not connect. Any solution would be really helpful.

[image]